# C++ openssl - Generate RSA Keypair and read

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa, key-pair

I am trying to generate RSA keypair using openssl library and then read the same keys later. However, it fails. Sometimes it gives me this error:

> error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

And sometimes, it gives me this error:

> error:0906D06C:lib(9):func(109):reason(108)

What is the correct way to generate the keypair and later be able to read it ? Here is my code. If you run it, you will find that it correctly generates the RSA key pair but not able read them later.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <openssl/rsa.h>
    #include <openssl/pem.h>
    #include <openssl/err.h>
    #include <exception>

    bool generate_key() {
        size_t pri_len;            // Length of private key
        size_t pub_len;            // Length of public key
        char *pri_key;           // Private key in PEM
        char *pub_key;           // Public key in PEM

        int ret = 0;
        RSA *r = NULL;
        BIGNUM *bne = NULL;
        BIO *bp_public = NULL, *bp_private = NULL;
        int bits = 2048;
        unsigned long e = RSA_F4;

        EVP_PKEY *evp_pbkey = NULL;
        EVP_PKEY *evp_pkey = NULL;

        BIO *pbkeybio = NULL;
        BIO *pkeybio = NULL;

        // 1. generate rsa key
        bne = BN_new();
        ret = BN_set_word(bne, e);
        if (ret != 1) {
            goto free_all;
        }

        r = RSA_new();
        ret = RSA_generate_key_ex(r, bits, bne, NULL);
        if (ret != 1) {
            goto free_all;
        }

        // 2. save public key
        //bp_public = BIO_new_file("public.pem", "w+");
        bp_public = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
        ret = PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(bp_public, r);
        if (ret != 1) {
            goto free_all;
        }

        // 3. save private key
        //bp_private = BIO_new_file("private.pem", "w+");
        bp_private = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
        ret = PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bp_private, r, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

        //4. Get the keys are PEM formatted strings
        pri_len = BIO_pending(bp_private);
        pub_len = BIO_pending(bp_public);

        pri_key = (char*) malloc(pri_len + 1);
        pub_key = (char*) malloc(pub_len + 1);

        BIO_read(bp_private, pri_key, pri_len);
        BIO_read(bp_public, pub_key, pub_len);

        pri_key[pri_len] = '\0';
        pub_key[pub_len] = '\0';

        printf("\n%s\n%s\n", pri_key, pub_key);

        //verify if you are able to re-construct the keys
        pbkeybio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*) pub_key, -1);
        if (pbkeybio == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
        evp_pbkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(pbkeybio, &evp_pbkey, NULL, NULL);
        if (evp_pbkey == NULL) {
            char buffer[120];
            ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buffer);
            printf("Error reading public key:%s\n", buffer);
        }

        pkeybio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*) pri_key, -1);
        if (pkeybio == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
        evp_pkey = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(pkeybio, &evp_pkey, NULL, NULL);
        if (evp_pbkey == NULL) {
            char buffer[120];
            ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buffer);
            printf("Error reading private key:%s\n", buffer);
        }

        BIO_free(pbkeybio);
        BIO_free(pkeybio);

        // 4. free
        free_all:

        BIO_free_all(bp_public);
        BIO_free_all(bp_private);
        RSA_free(r);
        BN_free(bne);

        return (ret == 1);
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        generate_key();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "Sometimes"? This suggests uninitialized data which wouldn't surprise me, looking at the code. Use `valgrind` or a similar memory debugger. Also, reduce your code to get closer to a [mcve].

Comment: The error is essentially the same, just sometimes you seem to have loaded error strings, and sometimes not, see: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/ERR_load_crypto_strings.html

Comment: By sometimes, I meant - on linux, I get the first one, on Mac I get the second one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks good to me. Except on reloading; I would have used PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey in stead of PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY.
I am not sure it is the best way to do it though.

```
--- /tmp/stack_openssl.cpp.back 2018-05-25 12:53:12.366488025 +0000
+++ /tmp/stack_openssl.cpp  2018-05-25 13:57:20.614066828 +0000
@@ -18,6 +18,8 @@
   int bits = 2048;
   unsigned long e = RSA_F4;

+  RSA *pb_rsa = NULL;
+  RSA *p_rsa = NULL;
   EVP_PKEY *evp_pbkey = NULL;
   EVP_PKEY *evp_pkey = NULL;

@@ -66,27 +68,32 @@
   printf("\n%s\n%s\n", pri_key, pub_key);

   //verify if you are able to re-construct the keys
-  pbkeybio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*) pub_key, -1);
+  pbkeybio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*) pub_key, pub_len);
   if (pbkeybio == NULL) {
     return -1;
   }
-  evp_pbkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(pbkeybio, &evp_pbkey, NULL, NULL);
-  if (evp_pbkey == NULL) {
+  pb_rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(pbkeybio, &pb_rsa, NULL, NULL);
+  if (pb_rsa == NULL) {
     char buffer[120];
     ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buffer);
     printf("Error reading public key:%s\n", buffer);
   }
+  evp_pbkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
+  EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(evp_pbkey, pb_rsa);

-  pkeybio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*) pri_key, -1);
+  pkeybio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*) pri_key, pri_len);
   if (pkeybio == NULL) {
     return -1;
   }
-  evp_pkey = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(pkeybio, &evp_pkey, NULL, NULL);
-  if (evp_pbkey == NULL) {
+  p_rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(pkeybio, &p_rsa, NULL, NULL);
+  if (p_rsa == NULL) {
     char buffer[120];
     ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buffer);
     printf("Error reading private key:%s\n", buffer);
   }
+  evp_pkey = EVP_PKEY_new(); 
+  EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(evp_pkey, p_rsa);

   BIO_free(pbkeybio);
   BIO_free(pkeybio);
```

Comment: That indeed was the case - since I was using the function PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey() to save the key, the equivalent method PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey() should be used to read, instead of PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY()